# Normalizing [data-structures]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I feel that something should be done about [data-structures](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures).  For instance, [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141049/convert-integer-to-roman-numeral) appears to include the tag just because it uses data structures.  Also, we already have many specific tags for data structures ([array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array), [stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack), [tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree), ...), so this one seems to be added to such questions as well.

Are there still legitimate uses for this tag?  If so, should we just untag it from open questions (no need to touch closed ones) that aren't specifically about data structures?

Comment: I'm voting to close this tag as too broad.

Comment: [possibly interesting search](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures+-stack+-hash-table+-linked-list+-tree+-graph+-array+-heap+-trie)

Comment: @SimonForsberg: Fortunately, at a glance, not very many of those questions may need a separate tag.

Comment: [Here's one with two additional data structures and no closed questions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+%5Bdata-structures%5D+-%5Bstack%5D+-%5Bhash-table%5D+-%5Blinked-list%5D+-%5Btree%5D+-%5Bgraph%5D+-%5Barray%5D+-%5Bheap%5D+-%5Btrie%5D+-%5Bset%5D+-%5Bdictionary%5D+-%5Bqueue%5D).

Comment: `0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]` Great job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with abolishing [data-structures](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures).

The tag can currently be used in three ways:

1. Redundantly along with some other tag, such as [tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree) or [stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack).  I think that in these cases, [data-structures](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) adds no value.
2. When the problem to be solved calls for some efficient data structure, but the author is unsure what kind of data structure to use.  In these cases, [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) would already cover the issue.
3. When the question is about an implementation of a data structure for which we do not already have a tag (such as a union-find data structure, a skip list, a Fenwick tree, etc.).

I think we should create specific tags for the more unusual data structures, then burninate [data-structures](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures).

Comment: Agreed.  I'll also look through Simon's search query (minus closed questions) and tag as needed.  There were already some locked questions (which are somehow immune to Trogdor's powers), and I've already taken care of them.